# Consuming image from API and displaying it on browser in meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a API that returns image and want to display the image on the browser. I am using `iron:router` package. On the client side user click on a link which is a basically a server side `iron:route`. The route makes call to API and should display the response of API on the browser.

client js : -

```js
Template.images.events({
'click .image': function (event, template) {
event.preventDefault();
var docId = $(event.target).attr('data-docId');
var imageType = "raw";
var param = {"docId":docId,"imageType":imageType};
params = 'width=' + window.innerWidth;
params += ', height=' + window.innerHeight;
params += ', top=0, left=0'
params += ', fullscreen=yes';
var win = window.open("/Image/?param=" + encodeURIComponent(Base64.encode(JSON.stringify(param))), "_blank", params);
}
});
```

Iron:route : -

```js
Router.route('/checkImage', function () {
var decoded = Base64.decode(decodeURIComponent(this.params.query.param));
var param = JSON.parse(decoded);
var docId = param.docId;
var content="";
Meteor.call('imageApi', docId, imageType, function (error, result) {
if (error) {
content = "";
} else
content = new Buffer(result);
});

    if (content == "") {
        this.response.writeHeader('200', {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            'Content-Disposition': "inline",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        });
        this.response.write('<html><body><p>No content for image found.</p></body></html>');
        this.response.end();
    }
    else {
        this.response.writeHeader('200', {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
                'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename=image.jpg'
        });
        this.response.write(content);
        this.response.end();
    }
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Server method : -

```js
imageApi: function (docId, imageType) {
var url = "API url with the paramters ";
var response;
try{
response = HTTP.call('GET', url, {
headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"},
responseType: "buffer"
});
}catch (error) {
logger.error("imageApi - Exception in image API " + error);
return false;
}

            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                return new Uint8Array(response.content);
            }
            else {
                logger.error"imageApi - Response issue: " + response.statusCode);
                return "";
            }
            return "";
        }
```

I am not able to display the image data on the browser. Do you think something is wrong in this approach or else if there is another way to render image.